# Oracle Equivalent to MySQL INSERT IGNORE?

Tags: oracle, insert, duplicates

I need to update a query so that it checks that a duplicate entry does not exist before insertion.  In MySQL I can just use INSERT IGNORE so that if a duplicate record is found it just skips the insert, but I can't seem to find an equivalent option for Oracle.  Any suggestions?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-skip-duplicate-key-errors-ora-00001-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check out the MERGE statement. This should do what you want - it's the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause that will do this.

Do to Oracle's lack of support for a true VALUES() clause the syntax for a single record with fixed values is pretty clumsy though:

```
MERGE INTO your_table yt
USING (
   SELECT 42 as the_pk_value, 
          'some_value' as some_column
   FROM dual
) t on (yt.pk = t.the_pke_value) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (pk, the_column)
   VALUES (t.the_pk_value, t.some_column);
```

A different approach (if you are e.g. doing bulk loading from a different table) is to use the "Error logging" facility of Oracle. The statement would look like this:

```
 INSERT INTO your_table (col1, col2, col3)
 SELECT c1, c2, c3
 FROM staging_table
 LOG ERRORS INTO errlog ('some comment') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Afterwards all rows that would have thrown an error are available in the table `errlog`. You need to create that `errlog` table (or whatever name you choose) manually before running the insert using `DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG`.

See the manual for details

Comment: Log errors will still throw an exception on unique or primary key violations, unless things have changed since:  http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1500471500346067777

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: It does work for `INSERT`s which is what Bad Programmer is asking for. But thanks for the link I wasn't aware that it doesn't work for updates on the PK (I only use it for inserts)

Comment: Should'nt the `FROM` keyword be replaced by the `USING` keyword ? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414747/oracle-equivalent-of-insert-ignore if needed.

Comment: FYI, you can also copy multiple rows with one MERGE INTO statement. You can insert WHEN NOT MATCHED and optionally update WHEN MATCHED.

Answer (score 32):

If you're on 11g you can use the hint [IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG):

```
SQL> create table my_table(a number, constraint my_table_pk primary key (a));

Table created.

SQL> insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(my_table, my_table_pk) */
  2  into my_table
  3  select 1 from dual
  4  union all
  5  select 1 from dual;

1 row created.
```

Comment: thanks this worked! but seems like such a non standard solution.. like how would anyone ever remember this notation.

Comment: @SonicSoul You're right, it is an unusual way to code.  The manual even notes that hints normally do not have a semantic effect.  Like all hints, this one needs to be used carefully.  For example, if the hint was misspelled there would be no compile time error, the feature would just silently not work.

Comment: yeah i recently arrived at Oracle development and am quite baffled by amount of these tricks to achieve what I used to think were simple things with sql :)

Comment: Might seem to be a bad idea though for perfomance as well according to [This blog](http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2010/1/1/the-11gr2-ignore_row_on_dupkey_index-hint.html)

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is but to save time you can attempt the insert and ignore the inevitable error:

```
begin

   insert into table_a( col1, col2, col3 )
   values ( 1, 2, 3 );

   exception when dup_val_on_index then 
      null;

end;
/
```

This will only ignore exceptions raised specifically by duplicate primary key or unique key constraints; everything else will be raised as normal.

If you don't want to do this then you have to select from the table first, which isn't really that efficient.

Comment: Tried it with jdbc and even though the pk was violated, `executeUpdate()` returned `1`, where I would expect it to return 0 as no row was updated. This prevents me from understanding if new data was inserted when using this for of insert.

Comment: If you're looking to identify PK violations from a secondary programming language @AlikElzin, this is the wrong question for you. Just do the `INSERT` and catch any exceptions in whatever language you're using. Every answer to this question will return `1`.

Answer (score 4):

Another variant

```
Insert into my_table (student_id, group_id)
select distinct p.studentid, g.groupid 
from person p, group g
where NOT EXISTS (select 1
                 from my_table a
                 where a.student_id = p.studentid
                 and a.group_id = g.groupid)
```

or you could do

```
Insert into my_table (student_id, group_id)
select distinct p.studentid, g.groupid 
from person p, group g
MINUS
select student_id, group_id
from my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution

```
insert into t1
  select from t2 
  where not exists 
    (select 1 from t1 where t1.id= t2.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

This one isn't mine, but came in really handy when using sqlloader:

1. create a view that points to your table:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_view
   AS SELECT * FROM test_tab
   ```
2. create the trigger:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trig
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON test_view
    FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
      INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES
       (:NEW.id, :NEW.name);
     EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN NULL;
     END test_trig;
   ```
3. and in the ctl file, insert into the view instead:

   ```
   OPTIONS(ERRORS=0)
   LOAD DATA
   INFILE 'file_with_duplicates.csv'
   INTO TABLE test_view
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   (id, field1)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

yet another "where not exists"-variant using dual...

```
insert into t1(id, unique_name)
  select t1_seq.nextval, 'Franz-Xaver' from dual 
    where not exists (select 1 from t1 where unique_name = 'Franz-Xaver');
```

Answer (score -1):

How about simply adding an index with whatever fields you need to check for dupes on and say it must be unique?  Saves a read check.

Comment: Because that will fail the insert if there are duplicates, when really you might just want to skip them.