# Oracle equivalent of INSERT IGNORE

Tags: sql, syntax, oracle11g, insert

I found a very similar topic on [Oracle Equivalent to MySQL INSERT IGNORE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332360/oracle-equivalent-to-mysql-insert-ignore)
However, I could not make work any of the proposed solutions. My case is a little special as my table does contains only 1 field, which is the primary key. Let's call the field "id" and the table "myTable" in the following.

**Using MERGE**

```
merge into myTable t1 from (
    select 42 as the_pk_value, 'TEST' as some_column from dual
) t2 on (t1.id = t2.the_pk_value)
when not matched then 
    insert (id) values (t2.the_pk_value);
```

This first attempt gives a `SQL Error: ORA-02012: missing USING keyword` error message. I have to admit that I did NOT understand the proposed syntax, so maybe I messed something when adapting to my pk-only-table. But as the showed example did not use any `USING` keyword, I dont understand where my error can be.

**Using hint**

```
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(SPSECU, PK_SPSECU) */ into myTable (id) values ('TEST');
```

This does work through SQL Developer, however it does not work from Java (I suspect OJDBC Driver to remove the comments to reduce transfer size.  BTW I could not figure out which JDBC driver I'm using... the Spring Tool Source bundle seems to connect without any further configuration to the Oracle Database. I see only a DERBY default driver installed.

**Using NOT EXISTS**

I could not make this syntax work. Here is what I wrote :

```
insert into myTable (id) values ('TEST') where not exists (select id from myTable where id='TEST');
```

I get an `SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error with this version.

**Using insert select**

I did not understand anything of the proposed solution by knagaev... trying to adapt it to my table gave me this :

```
insert into myTable t1 select id from myTable t2 where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.id = 'TEST');
```

Can someone help me ? I'm used to MySQL INSERT IGNORE simple syntax and am quite new on Oracle (using 11g version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge uses `using` instead of `from`:

```
merge into myTable t1 USING (
    select 42 as the_pk_value, 'TEST' as some_column from dual
) t2 on (t1.id = t2.the_pk_value)
```

Comment: Your syntax indeed work using SQL Developer. But... for some reason, the `ORA-00001: unique constraint (PK_MYTABLE) violated` does appear when called from Java. The error message does print the exact SQL query and it works perfectly when I copy-paste it in SQL Developer (first message : `1 rows merged.` following messages : `0 rows merged.`). Any idea ?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not a Java expert.  Perhaps post a new Java question with the code snippet?

Comment: I suspect something with the Oracle driver... For now I'll accept your solution, you gave me a valid Oracle answer (even if it fails through Java call).