# How to skip unique constraint error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert values into sql table, but I am getting this error in sql query

```
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (uniqueKey) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
       For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
       this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Is there a way to skip this error and continue insert. Something like this

```
try
   insert query
catch (unique constraint error)
   continue inserting other values
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9332360/409172).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There exists hint `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(<table name>, <unique index name>)`.

```
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> CREATE TABLE tmp (val NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_tmp PRIMARY KEY);

Table created.

HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tmp, pk_tmp) */ INTO tmp (val) SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

1 row created.
```

See that I insert three values of 1 and only one row was created.

Comment: Only caveats on the hint I would have is a) its silent and makes no record of the errors, b) its 11gr2 onwards specific and we have no version information in the OP. It does however work.

Comment: It always depends on actual usage, that why multiple options exist. It's just another option that should be mentioned.

Comment: an article about the hint http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2010/1/1/the-11gr2-ignore_row_on_dupkey_index-hint.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a `LOG ERRORS` clause which allows you to log the rows that cause errors in to an error table - this error table is created using a DBMS package:

```
DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG(table_being_inserted_into ,name_of_table_for_errors ,NULL,NULL,TRUE);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_errlog.htm

Function Signature:

```
 DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG (
   dml_table_name            IN VARCHAR2,
   err_log_table_name        IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
   err_log_table_owner       IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
   err_log_table_space       IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
   skip_unsupported          IN BOOLEAN := FALSE);
```

Then in your insert statement you end it with a log errors clause:

```
LOG ERRORS INTO your_error_table_name ( 'description of your choosing' ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

You can choose to accept a reject limit of a fixed number, allowing you to specify in effect a tolerance to errors before it throws a real error instead of just allowing the row to be place in an error table.

Answer (score 0):

simple sample is insert in `for loop` and ignore exceptions:

```
begin
  for rc in (select * from <your query> loop
  begin
    insert into t1(...) values (...);
  exceptions when others then 
    null;--ignore any exceptions do nothing 
  end;
  end loop;
end
```

other sample - same idea but use `FORALL` bulk operation and `SAVE EXCEPTIONS`

```
declare
    cursor C is
    select ID, OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, SUBOBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_ID, DATA_OBJECT_ID,
           decode( mod(rownum,100000), 1, rpad('*',20,'*'), OBJECT_TYPE ) object_type,
           CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME, TIMESTAMP, STATUS, TEMPORARY, GENERATED, SECONDARY
      from big_table;
    type array is table of c%rowtype;
    l_data array;

    dml_errors EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA exception_init(dml_errors, -24381);
    l_errors number;
    l_errno    number;
    l_msg    varchar2(4000);
    l_idx    number;
begin
    open c;
    loop
        fetch c bulk collect into l_data limit 100;
        begin
            forall i in 1 .. l_data.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
                insert into t2 values l_data(i);
        exception
            when DML_ERRORS then
                l_errors := sql%bulk_exceptions.count;
                for i in 1 .. l_errors
                loop
                    l_errno := sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code;
                    --do smth with the exceptions
                end loop;
        end;
        exit when c%notfound;
    end loop;
    close c;
end;
```

more information see on AskTom and OraMagazine

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:1422998100346727312

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html