# How to prevent insert if same records are present in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a query

```
    INSERT INTO FCC_CS_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID_MAP
(
"N_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID",
"V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID",
"V_TARGET_KEY",
"V_TARGET_INDEXNAME"
)
SELECT 
MAP_SEQ_TEST.nextval,
FCC_CUST_DIM.V_ALT_CUST_ID  AS "V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID",
FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_TARGET_KEY ,
FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_TARGET_INDEXNAME 
FROM FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK INNER JOIN FCC_CUST_DIM 
ON FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_SOURCE_KEY =FCC_CUST_DIM.V_CUST_INTRL_ID 
AND FCC_CUST_DIM.F_LRI_FL ='Y'
AND FCC_CUST_DIM.V_ALT_CUST_ID  IS NOT NULL 
AND FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.N_RUN_SKEY =290
```

Here I need to prevent the insert into FCC_CS_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID_MAP table if V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID,V_TARGET_KEY,V_TARGET_INDEXNAME columns values is already available with same value which is going to be inserted

How to modify this query to achieve that .?

Comment: Do you want to stop the whole INSERT, or just skip the duplicate rows?

Comment: you can put Unique Constraint for these 3 columns

Comment: BTW, why do you copy data between tables? Can't you just create a view, it will always return up-to-date data.

Comment: @jarlh : just skip the duplicate rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Duplicate Insert Data in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645765/prevent-duplicate-insert-data-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO FCC_CS_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID_MAP dst
USING (
  SELECT d.V_ALT_CUST_ID,
         b.V_TARGET_KEY ,
         b.V_TARGET_INDEXNAME 
  FROM   FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK b
         INNER JOIN FCC_CUST_DIM d
         ON b.V_SOURCE_KEY = d.V_CUST_INTRL_ID 
  AND    d.F_LRI_FL ='Y'
  AND    d.V_ALT_CUST_ID IS NOT NULL 
  AND    b.N_RUN_SKEY =290
) src
ON (
    src.V_ALT_CUST_ID      = dst.V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID
AND src.V_TARGET_KEY       = dst.V_TARGET_KEY
AND src.V_TARGET_INDEXNAME = dst.V_TARGET_INDEXNAME
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (
    N_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID,
    V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID,
    V_TARGET_KEY,
    V_TARGET_INDEXNAME
  ) VALUES (
    MAP_SEQ_TEST.nextval,
    src.V_ALT_CUST_ID,
    src.V_TARGET_KEY,
    src.V_TARGET_INDEXNAME
  );
```

Comment: My query return more rows with same valued columns at the first run itself (means V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID,V_TARGET_KEY,V_TARGET_INDEXNAME pair is duplicated). In that case it inserts multiple rows. How to prevent that by returning only distinct values (any distinct or group by logic works here?)

Comment: @ShanijP.S Just add `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `NOT EXISTS` clause in your SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO FCC_CS_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID_MAP
(
"N_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID",
"V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID",
"V_TARGET_KEY",
"V_TARGET_INDEXNAME"
)
SELECT 
MAP_SEQ_TEST.nextval,
FCC_CUST_DIM.V_ALT_CUST_ID  AS "V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID",
FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_TARGET_KEY ,
FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_TARGET_INDEXNAME 
FROM FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK INNER JOIN FCC_CUST_DIM 
ON FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_SOURCE_KEY =FCC_CUST_DIM.V_CUST_INTRL_ID 
AND FCC_CUST_DIM.F_LRI_FL ='Y'
AND FCC_CUST_DIM.V_ALT_CUST_ID  IS NOT NULL 
AND FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.N_RUN_SKEY =290
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FCC_CS_WL_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID_MAP t1 WHERE V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID = FCC_CUST_DIM.V_ALT_CUST_ID AND V_TARGET_KEY = FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_TARGET_KEY AND V_TARGET_INDEXNAME = FCC_CS_MATCHED_RESULT_BULK.V_TARGET_INDEXNAME )
```

Comment: My query return more rows with same valued columns at the first run itself (means V_SOURCE_REQUEST_ID,V_TARGET_KEY,V_TARGET_INDEXNAME pair is duplicated). In that case it inserts multiple rows. How to prevent that by returning only distinct values (any distinct or group by logic works here?)

Comment: Just add DISTINCT to the SELECT query

Comment: That wont work if you have sequence in the select statement