Check if a row already exists before inserting it
Here is the context of my problem I use the syntax Oracle SQL, and I would like to check if a row already exists before inserting it.
I already tried a solution with WHERE NOT EXIST / IF NOT EXISTS, however I have a constraint violation that is displayed and I do not want "error" in output, that is to say I do not want to delegate the error management to the DB but rather to the request.

TBH, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, so I'm not marking it as a duplicate, but if I understand the requirement correctly, I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9332360/2422776
